# How to render a html page without view model?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to render an HTML page without having a view model in Django if a page is going to display only static HTML?

Basically, I want to delete an issue from a webpage and then show a 'successfully deleted' static HTML page after deleting.

But I got blew error, anyone could help?

NoReverseMatch at /project/1/issue/14/delete_issue/
Reverse for 'nice_delete.html' not found. 'nice_delete.html' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

#### view.py

```
def delete_issue(request,project_id,issue_id):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue,id=issue_id)
    issue.delete()
    return redirect(reverse('project:issue_tracker:nice_delete.html'))
```

#### urls.py

```
    urlpatterns =[
        path('',views.list_of_issue,name='list_of_issue'),
        path('<int:issue_id>/',views.issue_detail,name='issue_detail'),
        path('<int:issue_id>/comment',views.add_comment,name='add_comment'),
        path('new_issue/',views.new_issue,name='new_issue'),
        path('<int:issue_id>/edit_issue/',views.edit_issue,name='edit_issue'),


path('<int:issue_id>/delete_issue/',views.delete_issue,name='delete_issue'),
    ]
```

#### nice_delete.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <p>Successfully delete this issue</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TemplateView` for this. Just add to your urlpattern:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns =[
        path('',views.list_of_issue,name='list_of_issue'),
        path('<int:issue_id>/',views.issue_detail,name='issue_detail'),
        path('<int:issue_id>/comment',views.add_comment,name='add_comment'),
        path('new_issue/',views.new_issue,name='new_issue'),
        path('<int:issue_id>/edit_issue/',views.edit_issue,name='edit_issue'),
        path('<int:issue_id>/delete_issue/',views.delete_issue,name='delete_issue'),
        path('deleted/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="nice_delete.html"), name='success_deletion'),
    ]
```

And use `success_deletion` url in `delete_issue` view for redirection:

```
def delete_issue(request,project_id,issue_id):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue,id=issue_id)
    issue.delete()
    return redirect('success_deletion')
```

Comment: It occurs a new error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /project/1/issue/23/delete
nice_delete.html. @neverwalkaloner

Comment: It works after I put nice_delete.html in the same folder as base.html. Thank you!!   @neverwalkaloner